# Excel IE Automation, trying to turn a value I'm looking for, into a variant

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this problem.. the code below is working and the result is as I expected, but I want to run this code for other tables, and the date and time in the condition changes for each table, however the format is always the same, I have tryied to use something like `If td.innerText = "*" & "/" & "*" Then` (in my understanding that should look for a value equal to "something/something"),  or even to set a format like this `Set y = "??/??/???? ??:??:??"` and try to find a match for `y` but it sems like I'm doing something wrong here.

```
'lots of code to get to the table and then... 

Dim tbl, td, tds

    Set tbl = IE.document.getElementById("table-pre")
    Set tds = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each td In tds
        If td.innerText = "01/01/2020 05:26:23" Then
            MsgBox td.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
            Exit For
    End If
    Next
```

Website code

```
<div id="table-pre">
<div class="pre_name1">Inverter:</div>
<div class="pre_value1" id="inverterSNSelector"><select name="inverterOption" id="inverterOption" style="margin-left: -150px;" onchange="selectInvertor()"><option value="'ST20K17001063'">ST20K17001063</option><option value="'ST20K17001066'">ST20K17001066</option></select></div>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
<table class="pretable"><tbody>
<tr>
<th class="prethtd">Inverter</th>
<th class="prethtd">Vpv1</th>
<th class="prethtd">Vpv2</th>
<th class="prethtd">Vpv3</th>
<th class="prethtd">Ipv1</th>
<th class="prethtd">Ipv2</th>
<th class="prethtd">Ipv3</th>
<th class="prethtd">Vac1</th>
<th class="prethtd">Vac2</th>
<th class="prethtd">Vac3</th>
<th class="prethtd">Iac1</th>
<th class="prethtd">Iac2</th>
<th class="prethtd">Iac3</th>
<th class="prethtd">Pac1</th>
<th class="prethtd">Pac2</th>
<th class="prethtd">Pac3</th>
<th class="prethtd">Fac</th>
<th class="prethtd">Temperatura (ºC)</th>
<th class="prethtd">Hora(GMT -3)</th>
<th class="prethtd">Energia hoje(kWh)</th>
<th class="prethtd">Energia Total(kWh)</th>
</tr>
<tr class="chart_list_even"><td class="prethtd">ST20K17001063</td>
<td class="prethtd">460.3</td>
<td class="prethtd">460.9</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">225.2</td>
<td class="prethtd">221.4</td>
<td class="prethtd">223.5</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0</td>
<td class="prethtd">0</td>
<td class="prethtd">59.88</td>
<td class="prethtd">34.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">01/01/2020 05:26:23</td>
<td class="prethtd">0.0</td>
<td class="prethtd">58890.8</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried `If td.innerText Like "*/*" Then`  ?   `Like "##/##/#### ##:##:##"` should also work.

Comment: Hello again Tim! I was using ´=´ instead of ´Like´, now with your code ´If td.innerText Like "*/*" Then´ it is working, what is the difference between them? Thank you.

Comment: `Like` is for pattern/wildcard matching and `=` doesn't do that.

Comment: Is there an public url to test with please?